# Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#

I get this error :

> Error 2   Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type
>   'Update_Automation_Report_In_ALM.OtaApi' is less accessible than
>   method
>   'Update_Automation_Report_In_ALM.reportTab.reportTab(System.Windows.Forms.TextBox,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel,
>   System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel,
>   Update_Automation_Report_In_ALM.OtaApi)'  C:\Users\eitansh\Desktop\Update
>   Automation Report In ALM\Update Automation Report In
>   ALM\reportTab.cs  28  16  Update Automation Report In ALM

this is my Form1 :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OtaApi ota = new OtaApi();
        private string windowsUsername;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var rt = new reportTab(statusBox, toolStripVersionLabel, toolStripUsernameLabel, ota);

        }
}
```

and this reportTabl :

```
public partial class reportTab : Form
    {

        private string selectedPlatform;
        private TextBox statusBox;
        private ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripVersionLabel;
        private ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripUsernameLabel;
        private OtaApi ota;


        public reportTab(TextBox statusBox, ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripVersionLabel, ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripUsernameLabel, OtaApi ota)
        {
            this.statusBox = statusBox;
            this.toolStripVersionLabel = toolStripVersionLabel;
            this.toolStripUsernameLabel = toolStripUsernameLabel;
            this.ota = ota;
            InitializeComponent();



        }
}
```

can anyone see the problem ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The class *Update_Automation_Report_In_ALM.OtaApi* is probably internal, but you are passing it to the method which is public. Thus the *Update_Automation_Report_In_ALM.OtaApi* is less accessible than the method.